# Set command parameter of a subreport equal to a main report parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

In my main report, I insert a number for column ID into the selection criteria. It grabs all relevant information where the ID matches.

Now I have a subreport that uses a `COMMAND` with a SQL Query. Inside, there is a `WHERE` clause `where ID = {?PM-ID}`.

How can I configure my SQL Query to pull in the specific ID value I entered into the selection Criteria of the main Report?

Comment: Please post example code and/or expected output.

Comment: you have to pass in the column id as a variable from the main report to the subreport, or i guess you could make a new table that will store the id for you, then either delete the row or add another column that will mark it as used when you are done with the SELECT query

Answer (score 1):

Try this, right click on Subreport > Change Sub reports Links

In that window you have to match the ID with the respective column in your sql query.